# Program running on qnx momentics giving error undefined references

Tags: sockets, qnx-neutrino

I am trying to run a socket programming on qnx momentics on IDE 4.7 , the code was written by someone else , it is getting compiled on his pc i was just asked to build it and run on our target. I am getting this error., The code has both  and , but it is throwing error "undefined reference to 'accept'" ,"undefined reference to 'bind'","undefined reference to 'listen'", my pc is windows 7, could anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you include just a header file, all the methods and variables are accessible and resolved.
But when you actually try to build the project, it starts looking for that method definitions and if not found, throw an error.

Example:
HAM in QNX,
I wanted to use these lines,

```
ham_entity_t *ehdl;
ham_condition_t *chdl;
ham_action_t *ahdl;

ham_connect(0);
```

and I just included,

```
#include "ha/ham.h"
```

So far so good, but when I tried to build using QNX IDE, it gave me the error `undefined reference`

Then, I followed this steps.

1. Right click project, go in properties.
2. Go to QNC C/C++ project on right side navigation.
3. Go to Linker Tab
4. Select Extra Libraries from categories.
5. Click add and type "ham" and rebuild the project.

Now in your case, only in last step you have to type "socket" and rebuild the project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Link the libraries manually. For examples if you are using a Makefile project then add the below line

```
LIBS += -L<Path to QNX SDP>\target\qnx7\aarch64le\lib -lsocket
```

and then rebuild the project